# Why does select SCOPE_IDENTITY() return a decimal instead of an integer?

Tags: sql-server, primary-key, scope-identity

So I have a table with an identity column as the primary key, so it is an integer. So, why does `SCOPE_IDENTITY()` always return a decimal value instead of an int to my C# application? This is really annoying since decimal values will not implicitly convert to integers in C#, which means I now have to rewrite a bunch of stuff and have a lot of helper methods because I use SQL Server and Postgres, which Postgres does return an integer for the equivalent function..

Why does `SCOPE_IDENTITY()` not just return a plain integer? Are there people out there that commonly use decimal/non-identity values for primary keys?

Answer (score 116, accepted):

In SQL Server, the `IDENTITY` property can be assigned to `tinyint`, `smallint`, `int`, `bigint`, `decimal(p, 0)`, or `numeric(p, 0)` columns. Therefore the `SCOPE_IDENTITY` function has to return a data type that can encompass all of the above.

As previous answers have said, just cast it to `int` on the server before returning it, then ADO.NET will detect its type as you expect.

Comment: `SCOPE_IDENTITY` function return value is ***decimal(38,0)***

Answer (score 40):

Can't you just cast it before returning it from your query or stored proc (SPs alway return int anyway, but maybe you are using an output parameter)?

Like `SELECT CAST(SCOPE_IDENTITY() AS INT) AS LAST_IDENTITY`

And why it does this?  Probably to be more flexible and handle larger numbers.

Comment: `SCOPE_IDENTITY` is a built in function.. so when doing like `ExecuteScalar('insert...; select scope_identity());` it will return a decimal from that function rather than the expected int.

Comment: @Earlz, so change the SQL to ExecuteScalar('insert...; select CAST(scope_identity() AS int)');

Answer (score 5):

try using this and you'll get an integer back:

```
ExecuteScalar('insert...; select CONVERT(int,scope_identity())');
```

Answer (score 4):

[Scope identity](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms190315.aspx) return value is decimal(38,0)

CAST it, use the OUTPUT clause, or assign to an output parameter rather than `SELECT SCOPE_IDENTITY()` to the client

Comment: In my case the column has the data type `int` but `SCOPE_IDENTITY()` for some reason returns `System.Decimal`... The `OUTPUT` clause returns an integer as expected, so thanks!

Answer (score 0):

This isn't an exact answer to the question as asked, but in the vein of the answers above, how about (in T-SQL - MS SQLServer):

select convert(bigint, SCOPE_IDENTITY())