# EntityFramework Why the decimal type is as int?

Tags: entity-framework

I have a stored procedure which return SCOPE_IDENTITY() ->int.

Then, if I import that SP in the EF file (Add Function Import), I see something weird.

**Mappings in the .edmx file**

[image]

**when import that SP:**

[image]

Why the column `Id` is treated as `int` and in the SP as a `decimal` ? (I know I can cast scope_identity() as int)

Comment: see this thread http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2601620/why-does-select-scope-identity-return-a-decimal-instead-of-an-integer