# How do I perform an insert and return inserted identity with Dapper?

Tags: c#, sql-server, dapper

How do I perform an insert to database and return inserted identity with Dapper?

I've tried something like this:

```
string sql = "DECLARE @ID int; " +
             "INSERT INTO [MyTable] ([Stuff]) VALUES (@Stuff); " +
             "SELECT @ID = SCOPE_IDENTITY()";

var id = connection.Query<int>(sql, new { Stuff = mystuff}).First();
```

But it did't work.

@Marc Gravell thanks, for reply.
I've tried your solution but, still same exception trace is below

```
System.InvalidCastException: Specified cast is not valid

at Dapper.SqlMapper.<QueryInternal>d__a`1.MoveNext() in (snip)\Dapper\SqlMapper.cs:line 610
at System.Collections.Generic.List`1..ctor(IEnumerable`1 collection)
at System.Linq.Enumerable.ToList[TSource](IEnumerable`1 source)
at Dapper.SqlMapper.Query[T](IDbConnection cnn, String sql, Object param, IDbTransaction transaction, Boolean buffered, Nullable`1 commandTimeout, Nullable`1 commandType) in (snip)\Dapper\SqlMapper.cs:line 538
at Dapper.SqlMapper.Query[T](IDbConnection cnn, String sql, Object param) in (snip)\Dapper\SqlMapper.cs:line 456
```

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33681176 if trying to insert/return for multiple records.

Answer (score 392, accepted):

It does *support* input/output parameters (including `RETURN` value) if you use `DynamicParameters`, but in this case the simpler option is simply:

```cs
var id = connection.QuerySingle<int>( @"
INSERT INTO [MyTable] ([Stuff]) VALUES (@Stuff);
SELECT CAST(SCOPE_IDENTITY() as int)", new { Stuff = mystuff});
```

Note that on more recent versions of SQL Server (2005+) you can use the `OUTPUT` clause:

```cs
var id = connection.QuerySingle<int>( @"
INSERT INTO [MyTable] ([Stuff])
OUTPUT INSERTED.Id
VALUES (@Stuff);", new { Stuff = mystuff});
```

Comment: Oh, one more thing. I'm not using .NET 4.0 and dynamic features

Comment: @ppiotrowicz hmmm.... darn SCOPEIDENTITY is going to return `numeric`, eh? Perhaps use your original code and `select @id` ? (this just adds a cast). I will make a note to make sure this works automatically in future dapper builds. Another option for now is `select cast(SCOPE_IDENTITY() as int)` - again, a bit ugly. I will fix this.

Comment: @MarcGravell: Wow! Great Marc, that's a good one! I didn't realize that `scope_identity` return type is `numeric(38,0)`. +1 a really good find. Never though of it really and I'm sure I'm not the only one.

Comment: @MarcGravell just wondering if you had tried making the automatic conversion happen. I ran into this recently. The TSQL cast works, but it would be nice to not have to do that. Thanks!

Comment: @Ronnie yes; in a recent build I **hugely** improved this for when binding *to an object*, i.e. `Query<Foo>(sql, ...)` - however, the simpler case of `Query<int>(sql, ...)` needs a little bit of love to bring it up to the same standard. There is a work-item logged to do that.

Comment: @MarcGravell: I am having the same problem with calling return from a stored procedure.  The primary key field is a bigint and I even set a local variable of type bigint to the SCOPE_IDENTITY() variable before returning the variable.  When I call execute and pass a long generic parameter, it fails with the "Specified cast is not valid".  I have the following question, pertaining to this issue: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17197018/dapper-getting-specified-cast-is-not-valid-for-returnvalue-parameter-value

Comment: Hey, this answer is the number one hit for getting an identity value back from a dapper query.  You mentioned that this is hugely improved when binding to an object; can you edit and give an update as to how you'd do this now?  I checked revisions in the Tests file on github near your Nov26'12 comment but don't see anything related to the question :/ My assumption is to `Query<foo>` that inserts values then selects * where id = SCOPE_IDENTITY().

Comment: @MarcGravell this method obviously breaks the CQS principle, do you think that the principle could be neglected in this instance?

Comment: @Xerxes what makes you think this violates CQS? CQS isn't about whether a SQL operation returns a grid. This is a command, pure and simple. This is not a query in CQS terms, despite using the word `Query`.

Comment: @MarcGravell but if its a command then shouldn't the return type be void? Id imagine that the method wrapping this will return the id.

Comment: @Xerxes the method wrapping this can return the id or not, as you feel free; however, *knowing the row id* is often a necessary feature in insert commands, especially if that command is part of a larger group. CQS is **not** about "does this method return void"; if you focus on that, you're missing the main aims

Comment: Nitpicky, but rather than use `Query` and get the first value from the returned collection, I think `ExecuteScalar<T>` makes more sense in this case since at most one value is normally returned.

Comment: `@@IDENTITY and SCOPE_IDENTITY()` are ***evil*** ? better use `OUTPUT Inserted.Id` ?

Comment: HOW-TO Dapper and OUTPUT clause ? https://www.sqlservercentral.com/articles/the-output-clause-for-insert-and-delete-statements

Comment: @Kiquenet note that the answer here does mention the `output` clause. Is there a question I can help with there? Dapper and `output` work just fine together. The linked article is not Dapper related, but yes: the queries there can be used alongside Dapper via any if the Query methods

Answer (score 74):

A late answer, but here is an **alternative** to the `SCOPE_IDENTITY()` answers that we ended up using: [OUTPUT INSERTED](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/queries/output-clause-transact-sql#syntax)

**Return only ID of inserted object:**

It allows you to get all or some attributes of the inserted row:

```
string insertUserSql = @"INSERT INTO dbo.[User](Username, Phone, Email)
                        OUTPUT INSERTED.[Id]
                        VALUES(@Username, @Phone, @Email);";

int newUserId = conn.QuerySingle<int>(
                                insertUserSql,
                                new
                                {
                                    Username = "lorem ipsum",
                                    Phone = "555-123",
                                    Email = "lorem ipsum"
                                },
                                tran);
```

**Return inserted object with ID:**

If you wanted you could get `Phone` and `Email` or even the whole inserted row:

```
string insertUserSql = @"INSERT INTO dbo.[User](Username, Phone, Email)
                        OUTPUT INSERTED.*
                        VALUES(@Username, @Phone, @Email);";

User newUser = conn.QuerySingle<User>(
                                insertUserSql,
                                new
                                {
                                    Username = "lorem ipsum",
                                    Phone = "555-123",
                                    Email = "lorem ipsum"
                                },
                                tran);
```

---

Also, with this you can return data of **deleted** or **updated** rows. Just be careful if you are using triggers because (from link mentioned before):

> Columns returned from OUTPUT reflect the data as it is after the
> INSERT, UPDATE, or DELETE statement has completed but before triggers
> are executed.
>
> For INSTEAD OF triggers, the returned results are generated as if the
> INSERT, UPDATE, or DELETE had actually occurred, even if no
> modifications take place as the result of the trigger operation. If a
> statement that includes an OUTPUT clause is used inside the body of a
> trigger, table aliases must be used to reference the trigger inserted
> and deleted tables to avoid duplicating column references with the
> INSERTED and DELETED tables associated with OUTPUT.

More on it in the docs: [link](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/queries/output-clause-transact-sql#triggers)

Comment: @Kiquenet TransactionScope object to use with the query. More can be found here: http://dapper-tutorial.net/transaction and here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10363933/transaction-with-dapper-dot-net

Comment: Can we use 'ExecuteScalarAsync<int>' here instead of 'QuerySingle<int>'?

Answer (score 58):

[KB:2019779](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/2019779),"You may receive incorrect values when using SCOPE_IDENTITY() and @@IDENTITY",
The OUTPUT clause is the safest mechanism:

```
string sql = @"
DECLARE @InsertedRows AS TABLE (Id int);
INSERT INTO [MyTable] ([Stuff]) OUTPUT Inserted.Id INTO @InsertedRows
VALUES (@Stuff);
SELECT Id FROM @InsertedRows";

var id = connection.Query<int>(sql, new { Stuff = mystuff}).Single();
```

Comment: FYI, this may be slower than using SCOPE_IDENTITY and was fixed in  update #5 to SQL Server 2008 R2 Service Pack 1.

Comment: @MichaelSilver do you recommend use ***SCOPE_IDENTITY*** or ***@@IDENTITY*** before than ***OUTPUT*** ? _KB:2019779_ was **FIXED** ?

Comment: @Kiquenet, if I were writing the code against a DB that was not fixed, I would probably use the OUTPUT clause just to be sure it works as expected.

Comment: @this works great for inserting a single record but if I pass in a collection I get `An enumerable sequence of parameters (arrays, lists, etc) is not allowed in this context`

Answer (score 7):

The InvalidCastException you are getting is due to SCOPE_IDENTITY being a [Decimal(38,0)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2601620/why-does-select-scope-identity-return-a-decimal-instead-of-an-integer/2601878#2601878).

You can return it as an int by casting it as follows:

```
string sql = @"
INSERT INTO [MyTable] ([Stuff]) VALUES (@Stuff);
SELECT CAST(SCOPE_IDENTITY() AS INT)";

int id = connection.Query<int>(sql, new { Stuff = mystuff}).Single();
```

Answer (score 4):

Not sure if it was because I'm working against SQL 2000 or not but I had to do this to get it to work.

```
string sql = "DECLARE @ID int; " +
             "INSERT INTO [MyTable] ([Stuff]) VALUES (@Stuff); " +
             "SET @ID = SCOPE_IDENTITY(); " +
             "SELECT @ID";

var id = connection.Query<int>(sql, new { Stuff = mystuff}).Single();
```

Comment: Try the <code>select cast(SCOPE_IDENTITY() as int)</code> and it should work in 2000 too.

Comment: did  you tried `select cast(SCOPE_IDENTITY() as int)` ?

Answer (score 4):

I was using .net core 3.1 with postgres 12.3.  Building on the answer from Tadija Bagarić I ended up with:

```
using (var connection = new NpgsqlConnection(AppConfig.CommentFilesConnection))
        {

            string insertUserSql = @"INSERT INTO mytable(comment_id,filename,content)
                    VALUES( @commentId, @filename, @content) returning id;";

            int newUserId = connection.QuerySingle<int>(
                                            insertUserSql,
                                            new
                                            {
                                                commentId = 1,
                                                filename = "foobar!",
                                                content = "content"
                                            }
                                            );

          


        }
```

where AppConfig is my own class which simply gets a string set for my connection details.  This is set within the Startup.cs ConfigureServices method.

Answer (score 3):

There is a great library to make your life easier Dapper.Contrib.Extensions. After including this you can just write:

```
public int Add(Transaction transaction)
{
        using (IDbConnection db = Connection)
        {
                return (int)db.Insert(transaction);
        }
}
```

Comment: This might actually be useful if you had put in what the transaction is.

Comment: Well transaction is your model (entity class)..

Comment: Good answer. The Contrib library is worth getting for this feature alone.

Answer (score 1):

I see answer for sql server, well here it is for MySql using a transaction

```
    Dim sql As String = "INSERT INTO Empleado (nombres, apepaterno, apematerno, direccion, colonia, cp, municipio, estado, tel, cel, correo, idrol, relojchecadorid, relojchecadorid2, `activo`,`extras`,`rfc`,`nss`,`curp`,`imagen`,sueldoXHra, IMSSCotiza, thumb) VALUES (@nombres, @apepaterno, @apematerno, @direccion, @colonia, @cp, @municipio, @estado, @tel, @cel, @correo, @idrol, @relojchecadorid, @relojchecadorid2, @activo, @extras, @rfc, @nss, @curp, @imagen,@sueldoXHra,@IMSSCotiza, @thumb)"
    
            Using connection As IDbConnection = New MySqlConnection(getConnectionString())
                connection.Open()
                Using transaction = connection.BeginTransaction
                    Dim res = connection.Execute(sql, New With {reg.nombres, reg.apepaterno, reg.apematerno, reg.direccion, reg.colonia, reg.cp, reg.municipio, reg.estado, reg.tel, reg.cel, reg.correo, reg.idrol, reg.relojchecadorid, reg.relojchecadorid2, reg.activo, reg.extras, reg.rfc, reg.nss, reg.curp, reg.imagen, reg.thumb, reg.sueldoXHra, reg.IMSSCotiza}, commandTimeout:=180, transaction:=transaction)
                    lastInsertedId = connection.ExecuteScalar("SELECT LAST_INSERT_ID();", transaction:=transaction)
                    If res > 0 Then 
transaction.Commit()
return true
end if
                    
                End Using
            End Using
```

Answer (score 0):

If you're using Dapper.SimpleSave:

```
 //no safety checks
 public static int Create<T>(object param)
    {
        using (SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection(GetConnectionString()))
        {
            conn.Open();
            conn.Create<T>((T)param);
            return (int) (((T)param).GetType().GetProperties().Where(
                    x => x.CustomAttributes.Where(
                        y=>y.AttributeType.GetType() == typeof(Dapper.SimpleSave.PrimaryKeyAttribute).GetType()).Count()==1).First().GetValue(param));
        }
    }
```

Comment: What is Dapper.SimpleSave ?

Comment: @Kirquenet, I used Dapper, Dapper.SimpleCRUD, Dapper.SimpleCRUD.ModelGenerator, Dapper.SimpleLoad, and Dapper.SimpleSave in a project I worked on awhile ago. I added them via nuGet imports. I combined them with a T4 template to scaffold all the DAO for my site.
https://github.com/Paymentsense/Dapper.SimpleSave
https://github.com/Paymentsense/Dapper.SimpleLoad