# C# Dapper get last insert id returns null MySQL

Tags: c#, mysql, database, dapper

I have two tables `Partners` and `Partner_Address`, I want to store partner addresses in another database. For that I use `Transaction` in `Dapper`.

After executing the query to insert new `partner` I try to get last insert id and then to pass that ID to address object, but all time I get `0`. Partner Record was successfully inserted but last insert id is `0`.

**Tables:**

```
// Partner Address entity

public class AdreseKorisnika   
{
    public int id { get; set; }
    public int partnerId { get; set; }  // partnerID
    public int adresaId { get; set; }  // addressID
    public string broj { get; set; }  // number
    public int status { get; set; }
    public int primarna { get; set; } // primary
}


public class Partner
{
    public int id { get; set; }
    public string naziv { get; set; }   // name        
    public string telefon { get; set; }  // phone
    public string email { get; set; }
    /// etc...
```

**What I try:**

```
public int InsertWithAdresses(Partner partner, AdreseKorisnika adreseKorisnika)
{                
    using (Conn)
    {
        string partnerQuery = @"INSERT INTO Partner(naziv, pib, maticni_br, telefon, email, web_sajt, status, created) 
                                VALUES(@naziv, @pib, @maticni_br, @telefon, @email,@web_sajt, @status, @created);";

        string addressQuery = @"INSERT INTO Adrese_Korisnika(partnerId, adresaId, broj, status, primarna) 
                                VALUES(@partnerId, @adresaId, @broj, @status, @primarna);";
        int affectedRows = 0;

        using (var transaction = Conn.BeginTransaction())
        {
            affectedRows = Conn.Execute(partnerQuery, partner, transaction: transaction);

            int id = Conn.Query<int>("SELECT LAST_INSERT_ID();").First();

            var addrs = Conn.ExecuteScalar<int>(addressQuery, 
                new
                {
                    partnerId = id,  // <-- here I try to pass last insert id from partnerQuery but it is always 0
                    adresaId = adreseKorisnika.adresaId,
                    broj = adreseKorisnika.broj,
                    status = adreseKorisnika.status,
                    primarna = adreseKorisnika.primarna
                }, 
                transaction: transaction);

            transaction.Commit();
        }

        return affectedRows;
    }
}
```

I want  my `Partners` to have one ore more addresses in another table. I also tried this:
[Dapper MySQL return value](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47160268/dapper-mysql-return-value)

**UPDATE**
[image: DB table]

[image]

**DEBUG**

[image]

Comment: AFAIK that code should work if the Partner table has ID set as AUTOINCREMENT. The MySqlConnection has also a non standard property called LastInsertedId. Did you check if this property is also zero?

Comment: that is just entity represetnatnion. Ofcourse my table have `autoincrement`

Comment: I tried to reproduce your problem but I get the correct value at every insert. I would try (but just out of better ideas and only to exclude some paths) to remove the transaction and check if somethings changes and, as second attempt, I would change the storage type from MyIsam to InnoDB. As I have said, these are just like desperation moves because I have no more idea to try.

Comment: Why is your query not in the same transaction as your insert?  That is likely the problem.

Answer (score 0):

I solved the problem like this:

```
public int InsertWithAdresses(Partner partner, AdreseKorisnika adreseKorisnika)
{                
    using (Conn)
    {
        string lastInsertID = @"
                            INSERT INTO Partner(naziv, pib, maticni_br, telefon, email, web_sajt, status, created) 
                            VALUES(@naziv, @pib, @maticni_br, @telefon, @email,@web_sajt, @status, @created);

                            INSERT INTO Adrese_Korisnika(partnerId, adresaId, broj) 
                            VALUES(LAST_INSERT_ID(), @adresaId, @broj);

                            SELECT CAST(LAST_INSERT_ID() AS UNSIGNED INTEGER);";


         using (var transaction = Conn.BeginTransaction())
         {
             var affectedRows = Conn.Query<int>(lastInsertID,
                 new
                 {
                     naziv = partner.naziv,
                     pib = partner.pib,
                     maticni_br = partner.maticni_br,
                     telefon = partner.telefon,
                     email = partner.email,
                     web_sajt = partner.web_sajt,
                     status = partner.status,
                     created = partner.created,
                     adresaId = adreseKorisnika.adresaId,
                     broj = adreseKorisnika.broj,

                },
                transaction: transaction);

            return 1;
        };
    }

}
```