# Dapper getting "Specified cast is not valid." for ReturnValue parameter value

Tags: c#, stored-procedures, dapper

I am trying to use SCOPE_IDENTITY to return a long primary key back to c# using the ReturnValue option for DynamicParameter.

Here is sample code from the Dapper website:

```
var p = new DynamicParameters();
p.Add("@a", 11);
p.Add("@b", dbType: DbType.Int32, direction: ParameterDirection.Output);
p.Add("@c", dbType: DbType.Int32, direction: ParameterDirection.ReturnValue);

cnn.Execute("spMagicProc", p, commandType: commandType.StoredProcedure); 

int b = p.Get<int>("@b");
int c = p.Get<int>("@c");
```

Instead of returning int, I would prefer to do the following as my primary key field should be bigint

```
var p = new DynamicParameters();
p.Add("@a", 11);
p.Add("@b", dbType: DbType.Int32, direction: ParameterDirection.Output);
p.Add("@c", dbType: DbType.Int64, direction: ParameterDirection.ReturnValue);

cnn.Execute("spMagicProc", p, commandType: commandType.StoredProcedure); 

int b = p.Get<int>("@b");
int c = p.Get<long>("@c");
```

In my proc, I am using "RETURN SCOPE_IDENTITY()".

However doing this seems to result in a "Specified cast is not valid." exception.

Comment: Can you clarify: is this dapper.rainbow? Also: you say the field is "bigint" - presumably now taking about the .net side. Here, do you mean `BigInteger`? Or do you mean Int64 aka `long`? SQL server's bigint maps to `long` in c#

Comment: Dapper micro-orm(Extensions).  When I refer to bigint, I am talking about the primary key field for the table I am saving to.  When I refer to long that is the .net variable I am trying to write to.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The return value from a stored procedure is always implicitly an integer, i.e. `int`. As such, you can only treat it *as* an integer. If you try to unbox it as a `long`, it will fail.

Options:

- if the value will fit, just treat it as `int` in the .NET side
- otherwise use an `out` parameter of type `bigint`, and treat it as `long` on the .NET side
- or use `select` and `Query<long>(...).Single()`

Answer (score 2):

If i remember correctly, SCOPE_IDENTITY() returns a decimal (http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms190315.aspx), hence the invalid cast exception.

You need to cast it to bigint (in the SQL) for it to work as you want it.

Comment: Or possibly a `bigint` in this case, since the OP is using `<long>`

Comment: tried this RETURN CAST(SCOPE_IDENTITY() AS bigint) and it is still failing.