# Dapper multi insert returning inserted objects

Tags: sql, sql-insert, dapper

Using [Dapper](https://github.com/StackExchange/dapper-dot-net) I would like to implement a method that takes an `IEnumerable` of objects of type `User`. Now, `User` looks as follows:

```
public class User
{
    public int UserId { get; internal set; }
    public DateTime DateCreated { get; internal set; }
    public DateTime DateChanged { get; internal set; }
    public string Username { get; set; }
}
```

The point here is that `UserId`, `DateCreated` and `DateChanged` shall never be set via object, hence the `internal` keyword. Instead the database will populate these values.

Because the objects are therefore modified as part of the insert operation I want to return another `IEnumerable` of objects of type `User` but this time with the corresponding properties populated.

Recently I realized that I can let Dapper loop through the `User` objects in the `IEnumerable` as follows:

```
public int Insert(IEnumerable<User> users)
{
    string sql = string.Format("INSERT INTO [User] (Username) VALUES (@Username)");
    return GetOpenConnection().Execute<User>(sql, users);
}
```

This is neat because I do not have to write the `foreach` myself. Now, the problem here is that `Execute` will only return the number of actually inserted rows.

So I tried it using `Query` as follows:

```
public IEnumerable<User> Insert(IEnumerable<User> users)
{
    string sql = string.Format("INSERT INTO [User] (Username) VALUES (@Username) SELECT * FROM [User] WHERE UserId = scope_identity()");
    return GetOpenConnection().Query<User>(sql, users);
}
```

However, this simply throws an exception:

> InvalidOperationException: an enumerable sequence of parameters (arrays, lists, etc) is not allowed in this context

I'm stuck with this. How can I make this work?

Do I have to loop through my input `IEnumerable` executing `Query` for each object inside loop body? This way the `IDbTransaction` parameter of the `Query` method would be useless if I want to insert all `User` objects in the same transaction so I'd have to wrap the entire loop in a transaction instead of passing the transaction to `Query`.

What is the "proper" way to insert multiple objects using Dapper and return the fully populated objects back to the caller?

Comment: This use case is not well supported by the Dapper library: https://github.com/DapperLib/Dapper/issues/960

Answer (score 9, accepted):

to insert or update List of object with Dapper.Net you can't use Query

```
 connection.Query<Object>("your_query",your_list) 
 //connection.Query<Object>: use to select IEnumrable<object> from db
 //connection.QueryMultiple: use to execut multiple query at once then read result one by one 

var sql = 
@"
select * from Customers where CustomerId = @id
select * from Orders where CustomerId = @id
select * from Returns where CustomerId = @id";

using (var multi = connection.QueryMultiple(sql, new {id=selectedId}))
{
  var customer = multi.Read<Customer>().Single();
  var orders = multi.Read<Order>().ToList();
  var returns = multi.Read<Return>().ToList();
   ...
}
```

you should use only Execute for multi insert or update

```
Execute("your_query",your_list, your_transaction);
```

so if you need to multi insert and return IDs for inserted records

```
// **using transaction depend on your needs**
```

//Example to multi insert and return full record

```
  string query = @"Insert Into _TableName ( _columns) 
                                  OUTPUT INSERTED.* 
                                values ( _parameters )"; //parameters should be same as object properties name to let dapper do correct mapping
```

**[OUTPUT INSERTED.*]**  will return full insert row with id and you are free to return any property by replace asterisk with propertyname **[OUTPUT INSERTED.Id]** will return only id

// will be good for small list

```
 for (int i = 0; i < youList.Count-1; i++)
                {
                    youList[i] = DbConnection.Query<object>(query, youList[i]).FirstOrDefault();
                } // for loop is better for preformance
```

//for big List you can use **SqlBulkCopy** review this link [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13722014/insert-2-million-rows-into-sql-server-quickly)

Comment: I was totally unaware of the OUTPUT INSERTED. From what I see this is a Microsoft SQL Server feature which, in my case, is fine because I'm using it anyway. So, that solves my issue with the insert query. Thanks for that hint!

Comment: I am using MySql and Stored procedure, what I will change in my code to achieve the same?

Comment: Valid for `INSERT Production.[TestScrapReason] (Name)  
    OUTPUT INSERTED.ScrapReasonID, INSERTED.Name, INSERTED.ModifiedDate  
SELECT [Name]  FROM [AdventureWorks2012].[Production].[ScrapReason]` ?

Comment: Caution: the example with the `for` loop results in a round trip to the DB per each record inserted. I don't think this should be considered the "proper" way.

Answer (score 0):

For MySql and .Net Core 2.2 you do it something like this:

```
public async Task<IEnumerable<T>> AddandReturn<T> (object dp, string SPName) {
            using (MySqlConnection con = new MySqlConnection (connString)) {
                using (MySqlCommand cmd = new MySqlCommand (SPName, con)) {
                    IEnumerable<T> resultList = await con.QueryAsync<T> (SPName, dp, commandType : CommandType.StoredProcedure);
                    return resultList;
                }
            }
        }
```

and to get the Id or object back from mysql, your stored procedure should be like this:

```
declare id int default 0;
insert  into objectTable(fields...)
    values (fieldvalue...); 
    set id=last_insert_id();
    select * from objectTable where objectTableid=id;
```

** Please note Mysql Stored Procedure Parameters names should be matching with the Object Properties in .Net Core.

Hope this will help someone using MySql stored Procedure and .Net Core