# Return id of record when insert or update or delete record

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-core, dapper

When I insert or update or delete an entity with Dapper, I need to return the `id` of entity.

I am using this code :

```
var role = await roleConnection.ExecuteAsync("UPDATE Role SET IsDelete = @isDelete, RoleName = @roleName, SecurityStamp = @securityStamp WHERE Role.Id = @id SELECT SELECT CAST(SCOPE_IDENTITY() AS INT)"
                     , new
                     {
                         isDelete = request.IsDelete = false,
                         roleName = request.RoleName,
                         securityStamp = Guid.NewGuid(),
                         id = request.Id
                     });
```

but it does not show me anything.

How can I do this?

Comment: What have you tried so far? A simple google search gives some results.

Comment: i search and try it but it not solve my problem

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do I perform an insert and return inserted identity with Dapper?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8270205/how-do-i-perform-an-insert-and-return-inserted-identity-with-dapper)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Well, in the case of `UPDATE` or `DELETE`, you already must have the `id`, otherwise you couldn't be calling any of these methods - correct?

In the case of an `INSERT`, if your table is in SQL Server and has an `INT IDENTITY` column, you can use something like this:

```
INSERT INTO dbo.YourTable (list-of-columns)
OUTPUT Inserted.Id   -- or whatever your IDENTITY column is called
VALUES (list-of-values)
```

and then from your C# code, use `cmd.ExecuteScalar()` (or `ExecuteScalarAsync`, if your prefer) to run this and get back a single, atomic value (the newly created `id` value):

```
var result = cmd.ExecuteScalar(....);

if (result != null)
{
    int newId = Convert.ToInt32(result);
}
```

Comment: in case of an update without using that Id of the record , is there is way to get the updated record id ?

Comment: @yasseros: yes - you can use that `OUTPUT` clause with an `UPDATE` command as well. Your best bet is always the [official Microsoft documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/queries/update-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15) for T-SQL / SQL Server for such things ...