# Expected: System.Int32, got System.Decimal

Tags: c#, nhibernate

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Why does select SCOPE_IDENTITY() return a decimal instead of an integer?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2601620/why-does-select-scope-identity-return-a-decimal-instead-of-an-integer)

I'm using following code to determine last inserted id on my column

```
var sql = "SELECT IDENT_CURRENT('TableName')"; 
var query = session.CreateSQLQuery(sql); 
var lastInsertedId = query.UniqueResult();
```

But when I'm try to use these id value

```
photo.Property = session.Load<Domain.Property>(lastInsertedId);
```

I got following error message
**Provided id of the wrong type. Expected: System.Int32, got System.Decimal**

How can I overcome these ? Thanks

Comment: please try session.Load<Domain.Property>(System.Convert.ToInt32(lastInsertedId));

Comment: make sense, please post this as your answer.

Comment: Check out this http://stackoverflow.com/a/2601878/570150

Comment: @panjo I have posted it as answer glad it is fixed for you

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`lastInsertedId` is getting returned as `decimal` you will have to convert it into to `Int` and pass it to the `session.Load` method

```
photo.Property = session.Load<Domain.Property>(System.Convert.ToInt32(lastInsertedId));
```

Answer (score 0):

You can write:

```
SELECT Cast(IDENT_CURRENT('Core.Clients') As Int)
```