# NHibernate.TypeMismatchException: provided id of the wrong type. expected system.Decimal got system.string

Tags: asp.net, sql-server-2008, c#-4.0, nhibernate, nhibernate-mapping

I am using Nhibernate in my application.
when I wanted to save a new object, sometimes but rarely-not all the time(this makes me suprise and crazy)- I came across an error which is called:

> NHibernate.TypeMismatchException: 
> provided id of the wrong type. expected system.Decimal got system.String

This error does not occur when I ran the program in my computer and in tablet PC.
but my clients can come across this error generally... Especially when they wanted to save a new record using tablet PCs outside the office. with outside word, I mean in tablet PCs, internet connection is provided with mobil sim card. They go to houses to get person information. Anyway, sometimes they can insert a new record at once, but for the second record, the error occurs again... after the error, it's impossible to insert a new record again. Therefore, they logout the app and when they wanted to login again, the same error is shown and it's not possible to login.

Database is MSSQL. id's are PK and decimal type. auto-increment is true.

I couldn't reproduce the issue at my side, so it's really hard to trace what the cause is about. The biggest problem is, it does not occur all the time... googling the cause for around 2-3 days... but haven't come up with any solution yet... weird error!

The hbm files are:

Hasta.hbm.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<hibernate-mapping xmlns="urn:nhibernate-mapping-2.2">
<class name="DataLayer.DBStructure.Hasta,DBStructure" table="Hasta" lazy="true">
<id name="Id" column="id" type="Decimal">
  <generator class="native" />
</id>
<property name="Aktiflik" column="Aktiflik" type="Boolean" not-null="true" />
<many-to-one name="Hane" column="HaneId" cascade="none" />
<many-to-one name="Iletisim" column="IletisimId" cascade="none"/>
<many-to-one name="HastaIsco" column="HastaIscoId" cascade="none"/>
<many-to-one name="HastaNace" column="HastaNaceId" cascade="none"/>
<property column="KayitTarihi" type="DateTime" name="KayitTarihi" not-null="true" />
<property column="KullaniciId" type="string" name="KullaniciId" not-null="true" />
<bag name="HastaCokluParametreDeger" inverse="true" lazy="true" cascade="all">
  <key column="HastaId" />
  <one-to-many class="DataLayer.DBStructure.HastaCokluParametreDeger,DBStructure" />
</bag>
```

Hasta.cs

```
    public virtual decimal Id
    {
        get { return m_id; }
        set { m_id = value; }
    }
    public virtual Hane Hane
    {
        get { return m_hane; }
        set { m_hane = value; }
    }
    public virtual Boolean Aktiflik
    {
        get { return m_aktiflik; }
        set { m_aktiflik = value; }
    }
    public virtual Iletisim Iletisim
    {
        get { return m_iletisim; }
        set { m_iletisim = value; }
    }
    public virtual HastaIsco HastaIsco
    {
        get { return m_hastaisco; }
        set { m_hastaisco = value; }
    }
    public virtual HastaNace HastaNace
    {
        get { return m_hastanace; }
        set { m_hastanace = value; }
    }

    public virtual DateTime KayitTarihi
    {
        get { return m_kayittarihi; }
        set { m_kayittarihi = value; }
    }
    public virtual string KullaniciId
    {
        get { return m_kullaniciid; }
        set { m_kullaniciid = value; }
    }

    public virtual IList<HastaCokluParametreDeger> HastaCokluParametreDeger
    {
        get { return m_hastacokluparametredeger; }
        set { m_hastacokluparametredeger = value; }
    }
```

CodeBehind side: after values had been assigned to related controls, save button is like below

```
     protected void Page_Init(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        _eski = base.GetBusinessLogic<ElektronikSaglikKaydiIslemleri>();
        Oturum ot = _eski.OturumBilgisiAl();
        oturumKullaniciId = ot.LoginEdenKisi.KisiId;
    }

     private void HastaBilgisiKaydetGuncelle()
    {
        try
        {
            _eski.HastaBilgisiKaydet(hasta, iletisim, cari);
            _eski.ClearHastaCache();
        }
        catch()
        { }
    }

    public void HastaBilgisiKaydet(Hasta Has, Iletisim iletisim, Cari cari)
    {
        try
        {
            this.Provider.Insert<Cari>(cari);
            iletisim.Cari = cari;
            this.Provider.Insert<Iletisim>(iletisim);
            Has.Iletisim = iletisim;
            this.Provider.Insert<Hasta>(Has);
            this.Provider.Commit();
        }
        catch (Exception)
        {
            this.Provider.Rollback();
        }
    }

    public void Insert<T>(T obj) where T : DBEntity
    {
        if (obj != null)
        {
            object newUniqueIdentifier = null;

            IClassMetadata tMeta = this.nhSess.SessionFactory.GetClassMetadata(typeof(T));
            if (!tMeta.HasIdentifierProperty) throw new Exception("'" + tMeta.EntityName + "' nesnesi için tekil tanımlayıcı(unique identifier) belirlenmemiş.");

            Type type = obj.GetType();
            PropertyInfo pi = type.GetProperty(tMeta.IdentifierPropertyName);

            //Özelliğin string olma durumuna göre tekil tanımlayıcı atama işlemi
            if (tMeta.IdentifierType.GetType() == typeof(NHibernate.Type.StringType))
            {
                newUniqueIdentifier = this.getIdentifiersNextValue<T>(obj);
                pi.SetValue(obj, newUniqueIdentifier, null);
            }
            if (trans == null)
            {
                trans = this.nhSess.BeginTransaction();
            }

            this.nhSess.Save(obj);
            InserLog(obj);
        }
    }

    private NHibernate.ISession nhSess
    {
        get
        {
            if (Disposing)
            {
                throw new ObjectDisposedException("Connection Provider");
            }
            if (_mySession != null)
            {
                if (!_mySession.IsOpen)
                    _mySession = null;
            }
            if (_mySession == null)
            {
                try
                {
                    MyInterceptor interceptor = new MyInterceptor();
                    interceptor.cp = this;
                    _mySession = getFactory().OpenSession(interceptor);
                    _mySession.CacheMode = CacheMode.Ignore;
                }
                catch (Exception ex)
                {
                    _mySession = null;
                    throw ex;
                }
            }
            return _mySession;
        }
    }

    public abstract class BusinessLogicBase
    {
    protected string SessionId { get; private set; }
    protected ConnectionProvider Provider
    {
        get
        {
            return ConnectionProvider.Current(SessionId);
        }
    }

    public BusinessLogicBase(string sessionId)
    {
        if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(sessionId))
        {
            throw new ArgumentNullException("SessionId");
        }
        this.SessionId = sessionId;
    }
```

In Insert method, it checks data type depending on whether it's string or not... It's added before because I built this application on the structure of the existing project. it's like an add-in. This existing project uses Oracle as database and IDs data type is string. so they increment their values one by one some using some custom features. but my database is SQL and datatype is numeric(decimal). auto increment is true. Anyway, that code in Insert method considering, I don't think it affects inserting process.

Comment: It's suspicious that it doesn't help when you reset the app. How are you managing your sessions?

Comment: @OskarBerggren I edited the code block again. During insert process, how I call the insert method, what the insert method includes and how nhibernate session is called for saving is added to get compromise very well.

Comment: do you use some kind of distributed caching, local-storage involving serialization ?

Comment: @jbl I haven't used them during the process I was implementing my code block as my app is just like adding web user controls and web pages only. so in the infrastructure of this base app, maybe it's been used or maybe not... I don't know that. well, what are they used for? are they necessary for multiple user accessing and querying or what?

Comment: Don't quite understand why you specify generator=native, but then assign identifiers manually.

Comment: @OskarBerggren I don't assign identifiers manually, when the entity is inserted, the database generates the id using auto-increment property. As I said before, the web app I developed is like integrated to another web project, so the previous developers have assigned identifiers manually, but for mine, it is not, because I indicate to Nhibernate that I use the database's auto generation id with specifying generator class as native-(or it could be identity as well).

Comment: @OskarBerggren Also, the issue that I have been faced made me think about the connection problems. The website and the database are handled in different machines(I am talking about where it's originally deployed when clients go to houses and try to insert new records; not in my computer). So when the network connection is lost  for a moment between those machines, could it be the cause of the issue? is that possible?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

anyway,
thanks guys who have wanted to help already.

solved the issue with the help of [this link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11844991/expected-system-int32-got-system-decimal)

I had gotta check session load method and i noticed i had to edit related code and it works all good now...

Probably, if you have come across the same issue again, this question and answer in the link can be one of the solution to guide you properly...

hope it helps...