# Store Primary Key after SQL Query

Tags: c#, sql, sql-server

Following situation:

I have a ASP.NET website for create VM's in an ESX environment.
The user can select some settings and click on a button to create the VM.

The Click-Event of this button checks the values and write it into an MS SQL Server.
The table has an `primary key (Integer, IDENTITY)` which I don't need to insert (because `IDENTITY`).

But I need this primary key, because I redirect the user after the event to another page and this page needs the primary key for regular queries (send it with querystring).

Currently, I make a SELECT query direct after the `INSERT INTO` query and take the last entry.
That works as long as only one user uses this page.

My question is:

Is it possible to recieve the `IDENTITY` primary key directly from the `INSERT INTO` query (like a return value from a function) ?

Comment: Are you using SQL Server or MySQL? `AUTO_INCREMENT` is MySQL terminology; SQL Server calls them `IDENTITY` columns

Comment: I use MS SQL, I'm sorry for this confusion, I learned both, MS SQL at the company and MySQL at school.
You are right, its `IDENTITY`

Comment: Thanks for clarifying. It looks like you didn't state your real question, which according to your comment on Mitch's answer is "how do I return a new `IDENTITY` value using `ExecuteNonQuery`?" If that's correct, then see [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14246744/executescalar-vs-executenonquery-when-returning-an-identity-value).

Comment: It looks good, but I have to tried it out on monday at work.
I'll report back on monday.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Off the top of my head, [@@IDENTITY](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-gb/library/aa933167%28v=sql.80%29.aspx) is what you want here.

That is of course assuming you are using MS SQL server.

eg `Insert into xxx.... ; select @@IDENTITY`

**EDIT:**

As Mitch Wheat pointed out, [@@SCOPE_IDENTITY](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-gb/library/ms190315.aspx) is a better option than @@IDENTITY. This is because @@SCOPE_IDENTITY returns the ID in the current scope, whereas @@IDENTITY may return an ID created by a trigger or a UDF.

Comment: SCOPE_IDENTITY() would be more correct. But it is unnecessay with OUTPUT clause.

Comment: Yes, SCOPE_IDENTITY may be a safer idea, but as long as it's just a simple insert statement (with no triggers or functions) then I think both should work

Comment: why risk it? use scope_identity(). But as I said, it is unnecessary if you use the OUTPUT clause

Comment: Yes I'm agreeing that SCOPE_IDENTITY would be the safer one to use. I'll update my answer to reflect that. It's been a while since I've wrote much SQL (the projects I work on are all EF now), but when I did, I preferred using IDENTITY or SCOPE_IDENTITY. It's just a matter of opinion.

Comment: It is not "just a matter of opinion"! : @@IDENTITY returns the last IDENTITY value produced on a connection, regardless of the table that produced the value, and regardless of the scope of the statement that produced the value. If you have a trigger on a table that causes an identity to be created in another table, you will get the identity that was created last, even if it was the trigger that created it.

Comment: Thanks for the response.
Question from my side, how can I use it together with [ExecuteNonQuery](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.sqlclient.sqlcommand.executenonquery.aspx) ?
Because normly as far as I know, this function doesn't return strings (primary key can also be a string)

Comment: No, I mean using @@SCOPE_IDENTITY vs OUTPUT is a matter of opinion

Answer (score 6):

Yes.

Use the [`OUTPUT`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms177564%28v=sql.105%29.aspx) clause

example from the MSDN link:

> The following example inserts a row into the ScrapReason table and
>   uses the OUTPUT clause to return the results of the statement to the
>   @MyTableVar table variable. Because the ScrapReasonID column is
>   defined with an IDENTITY property, a value is not specified in the
>   INSERT statement for that column.

```
USE AdventureWorks2008R2;
GO
DECLARE @MyTableVar table( NewScrapReasonID smallint,
                           Name varchar(50),
                           ModifiedDate datetime);
INSERT Production.ScrapReason
    OUTPUT INSERTED.ScrapReasonID, INSERTED.Name, INSERTED.ModifiedDate
        INTO @MyTableVar
VALUES (N'Operator error', GETDATE());

--Display the result set of the table variable.
SELECT NewScrapReasonID, Name, ModifiedDate FROM @MyTableVar;
--Display the result set of the table.
SELECT ScrapReasonID, Name, ModifiedDate 
FROM Production.ScrapReason;
GO
```

(Assuming you are using Sql Server)

-==========================

Comment: Very interesting, but how can I use it in this syntax:
"INSERT INTO VM (VMName, Memory) VALUES ('XXX',4);" ?

Comment: In a the same way as above.

Comment: You missunderstand me and I was unclear.
the SQL code is clear, but what is with the C# part. I work with [ExecuteNonQuery](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.sqlclient.sqlcommand.executenonquery.aspx)  to write the queries into the table and this function can't return the primary key.

Comment: Use ExecuteQuery() and a DataReader to read the results, if multiple. OR insert into a temp variable, select a single result, and use Execute Scaler()

Answer (score -1):

I think you can also use Sequence for your problem.

Sequence automaticaly generate series of unique number which can be used as primary key.

Comment: That's excetly what an IDENTITY column does. Answer is not helpful.