# ADO.NET Results From Stored Procedure as String

Tags: c#, asp.net, ado.net

I am eliminating the use of a really slow web service by connecting to the database directly via ADO.NET. The SP I am executing returns the results as XML (For XML Auto) and I am looking to store the response as a string. Would ExecuteScaler work or is their a better method of doing this.

```
SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("iweb_spx_controls_attributes", sqlConn);
cmd.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("@page_idASPX", pageID));
cmd.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("@user_id", userID));
cmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;

string reSults = (string)cmd.ExecuteScalar();
return reSults;
```

Answer (score 0):

This goes into some detail on your question and may be helpful.

[ExecuteScalar vs ExecuteNonQuery when returning an identity value](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14246744/executescalar-vs-executenonquery-when-returning-an-identity-value)

You can also search execute vs in google and see the auto suggestions it gives you.

Answer (score 0):

An alternative is to use the [`SqlCommand.ExecuteXmlReader()`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.sqlclient.sqlcommand.executexmlreader%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) method, which gives you more control over how you can interpret your result set (and would probably perform better if you have a large Xml blob to send back).