# when using ExecuteScalar it writes 2 Records instead of one

Tags: c#, sql, executescalar, scope-identity

I need to know what order number has been written to the database. To achieve this I use the SQL expression **EXECUTESCALAR**.

I debugged the program and monitored the database. The record is written once into the Database when I execute the 2nd Command it writes the same record a 2nd time. Can you help me out what I need to change so it does not write 2 records and I get my Order number back?

This is my code:

```
public static int CreateDocumentNumber(string userId, string todaysDate, decimal docprice, decimal docpaid, int packageId, int orderstatus)
{
    int orderId = 0;   //return value order Id

    //create order 
    string connectionString = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["conString"].ConnectionString;
    string insertSql = "INSERT INTO [dbo].[LD_Orders](TD_OrdUserID, TD_OrdDate, TD_OrdCost, TD_OrdPaid, TD_OrdPackage, TD_OrdStatus)" +
        " VALUES (@UserId, @Date, @Cost, @Paid, @Package, @Status);SELECT SCOPE_IDENTITY()";

    using (SqlConnection myConnection = new SqlConnection(connectionString))
    {
        myConnection.Open();
        SqlCommand myCommand = new SqlCommand(insertSql, myConnection);
        myCommand.Parameters.Add("@UserId", SqlDbType.VarChar).Value = userId;
        myCommand.Parameters.Add("@Date", SqlDbType.Date).Value = todaysDate;
        myCommand.Parameters.Add("@Cost", SqlDbType.Decimal).Value = docprice;
        myCommand.Parameters.Add("@Paid", SqlDbType.Decimal).Value = docpaid;
        myCommand.Parameters.Add("@Package", SqlDbType.Int).Value = packageId;
        myCommand.Parameters.Add("@Status", SqlDbType.Int).Value = orderstatus;
        myCommand.ExecuteNonQuery();  <---- FIRST RECORD WRITTEN

        // time to collect the last order id
        orderId = Convert.ToInt32(myCommand.ExecuteScalar());   <---- SECOND RECORD WRITTEN

        myConnection.Close();
    }
    return orderId;
}
```

Comment: Every `Execute*` call triggers an insert statement, so you don't need two in this function

Comment: THank you Zruty, so I just delete my first excecuteNonQuery and all would be fine then

Comment: Then mark the answer below as correct please

Comment: This is possible duplicate as I feel that what Rene is asking is present here. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14246744/executescalar-vs-executenonquery-when-returning-an-identity-value

Comment: You're executing the `INSERT` twice - so why does it surprise you that two rows are inserted?!?!?!?!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your code should work if you remove the line `myCommand.ExecuteNonQuery();`

Both `ExecuteNonQuery()` and `ExecuteScalar()` send the command to SQL server, the only difference is how they treat the result. Basically, you are executing two `INSERT` statements, which you don't need.

On a side note, it is very seldom justified to do hardcore ADO.NET coding nowadays. You typically save a lot of time if you use some [ORM](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Object-relational_mapping), like [Entity Framework](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/data/ef.aspx) or my personal favorite, [Dapper.NET](https://code.google.com/p/dapper-dot-net/).

Here's how you could rewrite your entire function using Dapper:

```
public static int CreateDocumentNumber(string userId, string todaysDate, decimal docprice, decimal docpaid, int packageId, int orderstatus)
{
    //create order 
    string connectionString = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["conString"].ConnectionString;
    string insertSql = "INSERT INTO [dbo].[LD_Orders](TD_OrdUserID, TD_OrdDate, TD_OrdCost, TD_OrdPaid, TD_OrdPackage, TD_OrdStatus)" +
        " VALUES (@UserId, @Date, @Cost, @Paid, @Package, @Status);SELECT SCOPE_IDENTITY()";

    using (SqlConnection myConnection = new SqlConnection(connectionString))
    {
        myConnection.Open();
        int orderId = myConnection.Query<int>(
            insertSql,
            new {
                   UserId = userId,
                   Date = todaysDate,
                   Cost = docprice,
                   Paid = docpaid,
                   Package = packageId,
                   Status = orderstatus
                }).Single();
    }
    return orderId;
}
```

Comment: Appreciate the feedback and the dapper.net suggestion. Thank you. I tested it with removing my line and it worked perfect.