# Why is calling T-SQL INSERT with SELECT @@IDENTITY inserting duplicates?

Tags: c#, t-sql, ado.net, sqlclient

I have a table with the following definition:

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[speech](
    [id] [int] IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL,
    [speaker] [int] NOT NULL,
    [speech_date] [date] NOT NULL,
    [subject] [varchar](250) NULL,
 CONSTRAINT [PK_speech] PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED 
(
    [id] ASC
)WITH (PAD_INDEX = OFF, STATISTICS_NORECOMPUTE = OFF, IGNORE_DUP_KEY = OFF, ALLOW_ROW_LOCKS = ON, ALLOW_PAGE_LOCKS = ON, OPTIMIZE_FOR_SEQUENTIAL_KEY = OFF) ON [PRIMARY]
) ON [PRIMARY]
```

When adding a new speech, I am using this stored procedure:

```
CREATE PROCEDURE [dbo].[add_speech] 
      @speaker int
    , @speak_date date
    , @subject varchar(250)
AS
BEGIN
    INSERT INTO [dbo].[speech]
               ([speaker]
               ,[speech_date]
               ,[subject])
         VALUES
               (@speaker
               ,@speak_date
               ,@subject);

    SELECT CAST(@@IDENTITY AS int);
END
```

If I run the SProc from SSMS only one insert occurs, and the new Identity key is returned as expected. But when I run the following code in my application, two duplicate rows are inserted! With different identity keys, of course, and the identity returned is the second one.

```
affectedCount = command.ExecuteNonQuery();

if (affectedCount > 0) 
{ 
    succeeded = true;
    newID = (int)command.ExecuteScalar();
}
```

**But**, if I don't execute the `command.ExecuteScalar()` in the C# code to get the `@@IDENTITY`, a duplicate is **not** created!

What is going on?

Comment: Does this answer help https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24690194/when-using-executescalar-it-writes-2-records-instead-of-one ?

Comment: for more context on what @PanagiotisKanavos says (they're absolutely right, btw) - see https://aot.dapperlib.dev/rules/DAP203 (also: Dapper will save you a lot of pain re data access)

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos - I was using SCOPE_IDENTITY and thought that might be the problem, so switched to @@IDENTITY. Of course it made no difference because it was my stupidity in calling ExecuteScalar(). The accepted answer shows how much I have forgotten over the past 8 years of being retired and only now getting back into coding.

Comment: @MarcGravell - Thanks, I did explain in a comment that I was using scope_identity originally, but was flopping around trying to throw things around hoping I hit on something. Obviously I was just being an idiot.

Comment: You don't need to check the rowcount. An unconditional insert will always insert, or throw an exception.

Comment: Yes, thanks, I knew that, @Charlieface. It was a copy/paste artifact -- had copied code over from an update subroutine, and hadn't modified it yet.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You executed it twice - once via `ExecuteNonQuery` and once via `ExecuteScalar`. Don't do that! Just use `ExecuteScalar` (since it returns one row and one column). If you explicitly need the rowcount, `ExecuteReader` provides that via `RecordsAffected` - or select `@@rowcount` as a second column (but then you still can't use `ExecuteScalar`, because: 2 columns)

Comment: @Cyberherbalist of course, if you're worried about the rowcount: if you use `output inserted.Id` (see the DAP203 link above), you could use Dapper with `var newId = connection.QuerySingle<int>("add_speech", new { speaker = who, speak_date = when, subject = what });` and *it'll do everything for you*, including asserting exactly one row is returned

Comment: If you want both you could also use an `OUTPUT` parameter.