# The SqlCommand.ExecuteScalar() function is not returning the Id of the inserted row

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc-4

```
public void Insert(Order order)
{

    SqlConnection con = DACHelper.GetConnection();
    SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(INSERT, con);
    cmd.CommandType = System.Data.CommandType.Text;
    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Category_Id", order.Category.Id);
    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Item_Id", order.Item.Id);
    con.Open();
    using (con)
    {
        SqlTransaction tran = con.BeginTransaction();
        cmd.Transaction = tran;
        try
        {
            order.Id= Convert.ToInt32(cmd.ExecuteScalar());
            new OrderMailsDAC().Insert(order.Id, order.Mail , tran);
            tran.Commit();
        }
        catch (Exception)
        {
            tran.Rollback();
            throw;
        }
    }
}
```

then I inserted the order.Id in the following Insert function of OrderMails Class.

```
public void Insert(int orderId,OrderConfirmationMail mails,SqlTransaction tran)
{
    SqlConnection con = tran.Connection;
    SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(INSERT, con);
    cmd.CommandType = System.Data.CommandType.Text;
    cmd.Transaction = tran;
    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Mail", mails.Mail);
    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Order_Id", orderId);
    cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
}
```

The problem here is that the order.Id value when inserted into another Insert of OredrMail then it stores zero at that place.. The Column is autoincremented , ad.Id which we have stored in Order table ...

Comment: Can you show the real text of the INSERT query?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [ExecuteScalar vs ExecuteNonQuery when returning an identity value](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14246744/executescalar-vs-executenonquery-when-returning-an-identity-value)

Comment: BTW - best to change `throw ex` to just `throw`. `throw` rethrows the exception as-is, including the stacktrace. If you `throw ex` the stacktrace starts there and everything previous is lost.

Answer (score 2):

`ExecuteScalar` returns the first column of the first row returned. Typically we'd just have the procedure select a single value if we're expecting to receive a single value.

in your procedure declare a variable like

```
declare @id
```

then immediately after your insert,

```
set @id = scope_identity()
```

then when the procedure is done executing

```
select @id
```

You can actually condense all of that to

```
insert ....whatever
select scope_identity()
```

I just have a tendency to be more explicit in case any other operations in between replace the value of scope_identity().

Comment: then i Inserted the order.Id in the Following Insert of OrderMails class method INsert.


public void Insert(int orderId,OrderConfirmationMail mails,SqlTransaction tran)
        {
            SqlConnection con = tran.Connection;
            SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(INSERT, con);
            cmd.CommandType = System.Data.CommandType.Text;
            cmd.Transaction = tran;
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Mail", mails.Mail);
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Order_Id", orderId);
                cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
        }