# How to get the last entered ID from database

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework

I am saving multiple photos to same `pr_id` into database. Each details are entering as different rows. So while retrieving I need the highest or last entered `photo_id` for each `pr_id`. How do I do that in C#?

My database table looks like this:

[image]

My view code :

```
    @if (Model.Photos.Count > 0)
    {
        <div>
            @foreach (var photo in Model.Photos)
            {
             @{ var last = Model.Photos.Last(); }
                @Html.EditorFor(modelItem => last.photo_id)
        </div>
    }
```

Comment: Do you want the id returned when you `INSERT`?  Is it an identity column/table?

Comment: Do you have Identity (auto generation of PK values) enabled in your table ? How are you inserting your record ?

Comment: Yes i need to return id

Comment: photo_id is auto is auto generated value

Comment: What have you tried so far?  StackOverflow is not a code-generation service.  Rather, we're here to point you in the right direction when you've made a concerted effort and you are stuck.

Comment: You can get the identity field value back from your insert query. look at the example somewhat described here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14246744/executescalar-vs-executenonquery-when-returning-an-identity-value

Comment: What is inside `Model.Photos` ? Is it all the Photos (for all Pr_id) or just the photos for a specific Pr_Id ?

Comment: its all the photos for all pr_id

Comment: What is your expected output ? You want to show all the PR_IDs and it's last photos ? Or you want to simply show the last photo( from all photos) ?

Comment: I want to show all the pr_ids and its last photo.

Comment: Do the insert through a stored procedure that also returns the last inserted it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are trying to show all the pr_ids and it's last photo, you should do a group by on your `Model.Photos` collection and then do an `OrderBy` on the grouped items and call the `Last` method.

```
@{
    var grouped = Model.Photos.GroupBy(a => a.pr_id);
}
@foreach(var item in grouped)
{
    <p>@item.Key</p>
    <span>@item.OrderBy(a=>a.photo_id).Last().Path</span>
}
```

Here we are simply printing the `Key` of the grouped item which is the `pr_id`. If you want more properties of the pr entity, create a class representing that data and use that in your LINQ group by statement.

Assuming `Model.Photos` is all the photo records for all the pr_ids