# SQL Insert command throwing errors

Tags: c#, sql

> ```
>  System.Data.SqlClient.SqlException occurred   HResult=0x80131904   Message=Cannot insert explicit value for identity column in table 'DriversDetailsTable' when IDENTITY_INSERT is set to OFF.   Source=.Net SqlClient Data Provider   StackTrace: <Cannot evaluate the exception stack trace>
> ```

I keep getting the above error when i run my code, not sure why. Here is my code:

```
SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection(@"Data Source = ComputerName\SQLEXPRESS;Initial Catalog = Drivers;Trusted_Connection=True;");
        conn.Open();

        SqlDataAdapter adapter = new SqlDataAdapter();

        SqlCommand command = new SqlCommand($@"INSERT INTO DriversDetailsTable (name, Id, DateJoined) VALUES ('Driver4', 1, '2017-07-06')", conn);
        command.ExecuteNonQuery();

        conn.Close();
```

Comment: Your SQL is the problem. do you have a 4th column at the beginning that is meant to be auto incremented?

Answer (score 3):

Yeah, that's cause your `Id` column is an `IDENTITY` column and so you should omit it in your `INSERT` statement like below. Since it's an `IDENTITY` column you can't explicitly insert values for it unless you set `IDENTITY_INSERT` to `OFF` which don't think you wanted to do anyways

```
INSERT INTO DriversDetailsTable (name, DateJoined) VALUES ('Driver4', '2017-07-06')
```

SideNote: don't see a reason for C# 6 syntax of string interpolation `$@"INSERT` when you are using hardcoded/static values

Answer (score 2):

Presumably `Id` is an `IDENTITY` column. As such, you shouldn't attempt to `INSERT` into the `Id` column - omit it from the `INSERT` statement, and let the database tell *you* what number it got assigned:

```
SqlCommand command = new SqlCommand($@"
INSERT INTO DriversDetailsTable (name, DateJoined) VALUES ('Driver4', '2017-07-06');
SELECT SCOPE_IDENTITY();", conn);
```

and use `ExecuteScalar()` to get the value back:

```
int id = (id)(decimal)command.ExecuteScalar();
```

(see [Why does select SCOPE_IDENTITY() return a decimal instead of an integer?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2601620/why-does-select-scope-identity-return-a-decimal-instead-of-an-integer) for an explanation of the cast)

Other options:

- make it not be an `IDENTITY` column
- temporarily disable identity insert during this operation if you need a specific value (not recommended in most cases)

Answer (score 0):

If you do want to be able to insert the id for some reason you need to set `IDENTITY_INSERT` to `ON` like so:

```
Set Identity_Insert DriverDetailsTable ON;
```

This can be done just for that particular command like so:

```
SqlCommand command = new SqlCommand($@"
Set Identity_Insert DriverDetailsTable ON;
INSERT INTO DriversDetailsTable (name, Id, DateJoined) VALUES ('Driver4', 1, '2017-07-06');
Set Identity_Insert DriverDetailsTable OFF;", conn);
```